# Printing certain items in a premade list (python)

Tags: python, list

I am making a program with lists and selection but I cannot get the programme to output only the sections of the list i want.
the error is somewhere in here:

```
print(randomlist[0,3,6,9,12,15,18])
print(randomlist[1,4,7,10,13,16,19])
print(randomlist[2,5,8,11,14,17,20])
```

Before it is asked:
The list works, it is with the right name, and there are 21 items in the list.
Error says 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' and I don't really know what it means

Comment: It means that you cant' do `x[y]` when `x`is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access multiple elements from a list by indexing a comma separated string. However, you should familiarize yourself with [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation).

Since you know the indexes of the elements you are trying to access, I think you're looking for this:

```
print([randomlist[i] for i in (0,3,6,9,12,15,18)])
```